# Plotting of ListLinePlot with proper legends and rendering

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, legending

I have four data sets in the form {f(x),x} as, [data1](https://pastebin.com/9GUwLWH2), [data2](https://pastebin.com/LNbReYFf), [data3](https://pastebin.com/9p2KjqUY), [data4](https://pastebin.com/XmhikWRd).

Now, I am trying to plot the four datasets using `ListLinePlot`. But I'm not able to get the desired result

```
    ListPlot[{data1, data2, data3, data4}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},PlotStyle -> {Red,Blue,Orange,Brown}, 
    PlotTheme -> "Detailed", LabelStyle -> Directive[Large, Plain, 24], 
    Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
    FrameLabel -> {Style["x", 24, Plain, Black], 
    Style["f(x)", 24, Plain, Black]}, ImageSize -> {850, 550}, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 2]
```

[image]

I wanted some of the curves to be dashed and some dotted, tried using `Directive`, didn't know how to make it work.
Is there a way to show `PlotExpression` (I tried it as well, didn't work), for e.g. red curve means `Δ = 0`. Similarly, blue means `Δ = -0.5`, brown means `Δ = +0.5`, yellow means `Δ =+1`. Kind of a research paper style on the right side of the figure?
Even `AxesOrigin` didn't work here, I wanted to be at `{0,0}`? Surely, I'm missing something.

Comment: Include `Dashed` , `Dotted` inside PlotStyle: `PlotStyle -> {{Dashed,Red},{Dotted,Blue},Orange,Brown}`

Comment: for legends try `PlotLegends -> {"\[CapitalDelta] = 0", "\[CapitalDelta] = -0.5", 
  "\[CapitalDelta] = 0.5", "\[CapitalDelta] = 1.0" }`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I think, `PlotStyle` is not working, because these are not smooth curves but data points maybe?

Comment: @kglr Thanks! It works. Just a naive question. Instead of color dot then `Legend`. Can we have a thick color strip instead of a dot? dot is just too small

Comment: try `PlotLegends ->LineLegend[ {"\[CapitalDelta] = 0", "\[CapitalDelta] = -0.5", "\[CapitalDelta] = 0.5", "\[CapitalDelta] = 1.0" }]`

Comment: @ Shamina I tried it using `ListLinePlot` instead of `ListPlot` , it works as expected!

Comment: @kglr I think, it's still coming as a dot, unfortunately.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Actually, `ListLinePlot` disrupts the data plot. Maybe we can use `Graphics`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We separate each data set into several paths using [`FindCurvePath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindCurvePath.html) followed by manual adjustments:

```
{data1a, data1b} = data1[[#]] & /@ FindCurvePath[data1];
{data2a , data2b} = GatherBy[data2[[FindCurvePath[data2][[1]]]], #[[2]] <= -1 &];
{data3a, data3b, data3c} = data3[[#]] & /@ FindCurvePath[data3];
{data4a, data4b} = data4[[#]] & /@ FindCurvePath[data4];
data4a = Rest @ data4a;
data3a = data3a[[4 ;;]];
```

Then we use `ListLinePlot` with input `{data1a, data1b, data2a, data2b, data3a, data3b, data3c, data4a, data4b}` and specify the list of styles so that parts corresponding to each data set has the same styles:

```
ListLinePlot[{data1a, data1b, data2a, data2b, data3a, data3b, data3c, data4a, data4b}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Red, Directive[Thick, Blue, Dashed], Directive[Thick, Blue, Dashed], 
    Orange, Orange, Orange, Brown, Brown}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Large, Plain, 24], 
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x", 24, Plain, Black], 
   Style["f(x)", 24, Plain, Black]}, ImageSize -> {850, 550}, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{Red, Directive[Thick, Blue, Dashed], Orange, 
    Brown}, {"Δ = 0", "Δ = -0.5", "Δ = 0.5", "Δ = 1.0"}]]
```

[image]

If you don't mind the vertical and horizontal lines, you can simply use [`ListCurvePathPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCurvePathPlot.html) without any additional processing:

```
ListCurvePathPlot[{data1, data2, data3, data4}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Orange, Brown}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Large, Plain, 24], 
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x", 24, Plain, Black], 
   Style["f(x)", 24, Plain, Black]}, ImageSize -> {850, 550}]
```

[image]